# How to mount a Gopro to DSLR?

Tags: dslr, video, gopro, support-equipment, tripod-socket

I am looking for a way to mount a Gopro to a DSLR but without using the hotshoe (already taken). That probably leaves the bottom of the camera available. The idea is to record video during photo shoots for use in the DVD slideshow.

Has anyone had any experience in doing this kind of thing or any suggestions on how to mount the Gopro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[$10](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/743055-REG/Vello_CB_600_Straight_Flash_Bracket.html) will get you a flash bracket that gives you a coldshoe or tripod thread to the right or left of your camera body.

Even cheeper than that is some scrap steel, and a 1/4"-20 bolt.

Comment: You could also use a flash bracket that flips - something like this http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/52728-REG/Stroboframe_310_635_Quick_Flip_350_Bracket.html Flipped all the way it would be in the way of a hotshoe mounted flash, but it can be turned a bit and locked down to any location that suits your need.

Comment: Isn't that a 1/4" bolt?

Comment: Yes, slip of the finger. Fixed now.