# How to take photos and video at same time for up-close action?

Tags: video

My boyfriend is a wrestler. During his matches I take photos for him with my DSLR (continuous shooting). For video, I set up a point-and-shoot camera on a tripod far enough away to capture all the action within the frame.

However, I'm looking to get up closer to the action for video, as I believe it provides a better viewing experience.

My question is, how would I go about this? I can't do both at the same time with my DSLR. Would you recommend I bracket the video camera to my DSLR or get a separate camera that I can attach to my face/body like a Go Pro, or get something like sunglasses that can record video?

I would like the video quality to be 720p at minimal, which is what my point-and-shoot is currently capable of.

Appreciate any help, thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried filming in high resolution and the extracting specific frames from the video?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't keep track of this but several recent DSLRs allow taking photos while recording video. This may result in a 1s or so interruption of video but you get a photo for that moment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about video that is not useful to still photography.

Comment: I'd recommend that you ask a friend (of you or of your husband) to handle a second video camera! (or a regular fan of wrestling that you see each time, or maybe your husband's coach?). They can follow the action, focus on what needs to be focused on, etc, much better than a tripod (or having the videocamera on top of your photocamera) would do.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a DSLR and video, a bracket is probably the most obvious solution.

Worth pointing out though: the Nikon 1 series has a feature where you can take a still image while shooting video (without interrupting the video).  It's not a single frame from the video, but a separately captured still image at full resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There are cameras such as the Panasonic FZ1000 that can capture 4k video. Each 4k frame is 4096 x 2160 pixels, which would be ample for use on the web, or even for printing up to 8 x 10 inches (20 x 25 cm). This also gives a great chance for capturing the perfect moment, as you are taking "stills" at 30 fps!

As @MikeW suggests, many cameras allow for taking single stills while shooting video. This provides higher resolution stills than 4k, in most cases, but if you try this option, use a remote shutter release, if possible, to avoid camera shake in the video (even using a substantial tripod) when you press the button.

Answer (score 0):

For using a separate camera, I don't think a GoPro on your head would be very useful. Because it won't be very stable, it will shake as you move. And you will probably be looking around to see what is going on, or looking down at your camera etc. So much of the time it will be pointing in the wrong direction.

Better to attach a video camera onto your DSLR. Then you just have to point that towards the action. You can get an adapter for your flash hotshoe, it slides in, and provides a standard tripod screw. So you can attach any sort of compact camera on to that. A GoPro or similar would work well for this, as it is fairly small and lightweight, and pretty good video quality.

Or you could use a bracket on the bottom of the DSLR,to mount the GoPro below or alongside. See this queston [How to mount a Gopro to DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56338/how-to-mount-a-gopro-to-dslr)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you hold your camera. I'd say if you can manage having a video camera on top of your DSLR and you can hold it steady that can work. The main issue is that it will be recording and you need to be conscious of it when moving around. A related issue is if your lens is too wide, you may be part of it in the video, such as a Go Pro.

A better solution I'd say is get a tripod (assuming they allow that) and place it near you with a video camera on it. That way, the video camera does **not** record yourself moving around. However, some people may prefer a more dynamic shot vs. a "passive" but stable shot so it depends on ultimately what you or your boyfriend want in the end.